# Graphics Problem on Ubuntu 12.10 Gnome 3

Tags: 12.10, gnome, graphics

I've been using 12.10 for about two weeks now with no problems.  The whole time I have been using Gnome 3. Then suddenly the system spontaneously rebooted.  When it came back up there were lots of obvious, seemingly random graphics bugs. Here's a screenshot:

[image]
.

What your seeing is just an empty workspace with one of the stock wallpapers right after log in.

Changing the background several times will cause it to randomly display correctly/incorrectly. The graphics get borked on individual windows from time to time.  I haven't been able to reproduce this with Classic Gnome or Unity, but this happens every time with Gnome 3. I really like Gnome 3 and would like to keep using it, but for now I'm stuck with Unity.

Here's some more info about my system:

- Model: Dell Precision M4600
- Memory: 7.8 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz × 4
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS
- OS type: 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I use is to restart the environment: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then `r`.

Comment: That works, but I have to do it any time after my computer starts or I change my wall paper.  I'm going to stick with Unity for now. :(

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem and I would also be interested in an answer. So long what I have seen is that the problem seems to be for AMD graphics. I haven't seen any Nvidia user having it.

Comment: Put a custom wallpaper into Pictures folder, get a beautiful one. It will fix the problem, when you suspend your computer or do whatever you do, the problem will not happen anymore. It seems to obly happen with the stock wallpapers. I am sure tough it will be fixed soon by Gnome 3 devs.

Comment: The behavior is exactly the same regardless of which wallpaper I use.  The graphics bug affects more than just the wallpaper.  It affect the windows, Activity bar etc.  If you open the screen shot at full size you will see bugs in the display of the Activity bar at the top left.